# Regular expression with parenthesis in datatable

Tags: javascript, regex, datatables

I am not well versed in regular expressions. But I am filtering my bootstrap datatable based on a column like this:

This will filter out any row in column 4 that has "HOUSE" in it

`myTable.columns(4).search('^(?:(?!HOUSE).)*$\r?\n?', true, false).draw();`

Now I wanted to write another search that removes everything from the same column that has "HOUSE(MAIN)" in it. I tried:

`myTable.columns(4).search('^(?:(?!HOUSE(MAIN)).)*$\r?\n?', true, false).draw();`

but it does not work.

Comment: `(` and `)` have special meaning in regex and need to be escaped to match literally: `'^(?:(?!HOUSE\(MAIN\)).)*$\r?\n?'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression for matching parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633533/regular-expression-for-matching-parentheses)

Comment: If you're just doing a simple text search, you don't need a regex; just do a text search with [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and check if it's greater than -1. Same goes for string replacement: you don't need a regex if you're doing exact text search. If you need to confine the search to the beginning of the string, your regex can be *much* simpler: `^HOUSE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(` and `)` are [`special characters`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in regex used for capturing or grouping items.

Because of this, using the regex `'HOUSE(MAIN)'` would actually match the string `'HOUSEMAIN'` but not `'HOUSE(MAIN)'`. I'm not sure if this is actually what you want (the comments might be of more help) but the regex would need to escape the parenthetical, so:

```
HOUSE\(MAIN\)
```